# Trying to install kernel headers but there seems to be a mismatch

Tags: linux, windows-10, virtualbox, centos7

In order to get VirtualBox 5.2 working on my Centos 7 VM, apparently, I need to install kernel headers. However there seems to be a mismatch on my system. When I run `uname -r` the following version is returned.

> 3.10.0-514.el7.x86_64

But when I check the kernels directory, `ll /usr/src/kernels/`, a different version is returned, as shown below.

> drwxr-xr-x 22 root root 4096 Nov 23 07:12 3.10.0-862.14.4.el7.x86_64

Notice the version difference between the two. Should these two values match?

I tried searching for the `514` version with, `yum search "kernel-headers-uname-r == $(uname -r)" --disableexcludes=all`, but there was nothing found. See below.

> Warning: No matches found for: kernel-headers-uname-r == 3.10.0-514.el7.x86_64
>   No matches found.

So the question is: Which headers do I install and if necessary where can I find the `514` version.

**System Info:**
Host: Windows 10
Client: Centos 7 - This is where I am installing Virtual Box and the kernel headers

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not about programming, but rather about RHEL(Fedora?/CentOS?) and belongs to https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/linux

Comment: Have you tried `sudo yum update`?

Comment: Really wild stab in the dark -- but have you rebooted since you updated the kernel??? (you may well have installed `3.10.0-862`, but if you haven't rebooted since, you are still running on your old kernel)

Answer (score 0):

1. find your kernel-devel at [this link](https://buildlogs.centos.org/), for example: [kernel-devel-3.10.0-693.el7.x86_64.rpm](https://buildlogs.centos.org/c7.1708.00/kernel/20170822030048/3.10.0-693.el7.x86_64/kernel-devel-3.10.0-693.el7.x86_64.rpm), then download it.
2. `rpm -i kernel-devel-3.10.0-693.el7.x86_64.rpm`

check /usr/src/kernel/ folder.